# I'm making a rhythm game with Unity program. It's a question about long notes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WqTn.png)There is a problem with the implementation of the long note.
Currently, the long note is made into an empty game object and a bar is inserted as a child of the long note's body. However, there is an error that the main body disappears and the bar disappears together. So, there is a bug that cannot be determined when it is produced separately, so how can I solve it?

---

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        // tag가 Note인 것과 충돌 할때 
        if (collision.tag == "Note")
        {
            // 노트의 이미지가 활성화 된 상태일때만
            if (collision.GetComponent<Note>().GetNoteFlag())
            {
                theAudio.PlaySFX("Miss");
                theStatus.cutHp();
                theTiming.MissRecord();
                theEffect.JudgementeffImg(2);
                theCombo.ResetCombo();
            }
            // 충돌한 오브젝트 파괴
            theTiming.boxNoteList.Remove(collision.gameObject);

            // Enqueue를 이용해 noteQueue에 노트를 반납
            ObjectPool.instance.noteQueue.Enqueue(collision.gameObject);
            // 노트 비활성화
            collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

This is the section where a mistake is made.

```
public void CheckTiming()
    { // >> PlayerController
        for (int i = 0; i < boxNoteList.Count; i++)
        {
            float t_NotePosY = boxNoteList[i].transform.localPosition.y;

            for (int j = 0; j < timingBoxs.Length; j++)
            {
                if (timingBoxs[j].x <= t_NotePosY && t_NotePosY <= timingBoxs[j].y)
                {
                    switch(j)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            theAudio.PlaySFX("Touch");
                            boxNoteList[i].GetComponent<Note>().HideNote();
                            boxNoteList.RemoveAt(i);
                            theEffect.JudgementeffImg(0);
                            theScore.IncreaseScore(j);
                            theStatus.IncreaseHp();
                            theEffect.noteEffect(player.NoteNumEffect());
                            judgementRecord[0]++;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            theAudio.PlaySFX("Touch");
                            boxNoteList[i].GetComponent<Note>().HideNote();
                            boxNoteList.RemoveAt(i);
                            theEffect.JudgementeffImg(1);
                            theScore.IncreaseScore(j);
                            theStatus.IncreaseHp();
                            theEffect.noteEffect(player.NoteNumEffect());
                            judgementRecord[1]++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            theEffect.JudgementeffImg(2);
                            judgementRecord[2]++;
                            theCombo.ResetCombo();
                            break;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        theCombo.ResetCombo();
        MissRecord();
    }
```

This part is marked so that you can produce a judgment based on the y value of the note.

The object with this script has a short note and a long note in a rhythm game, which is used to implement a long note.

Comment: Please ask me the first question and let me know if you need any information. I'll organize it and upload it.

Comment: Provide us more details: your bar disappearing code and which object has this script.

Comment: I revised the information you need and uploaded it. I'm sorry that I'm not good at handling the site because it's my first time using it today.

Answer (score 1):

Log the name of the `collision.gameObject` with `Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name);` that you are setting to false and ensure that it is the child element that you want to shut off. You may need to use `collision.gameObject.transform.GetChild(int i).gameObject.SetActive(false);` instead.

It sounds like **you're turning off the parent gameObject**. Remember, any time you turn off a parent, you will also turn off all of its children and no script will run on a gameObject that is not `activeInHierarchy`.

Comment: Good luck, remember that you can always pause your test play with Debug.Break() then you can inspect your hierarchy and see what is happening at the moment of the pause.